# Getting Consent from DocuSign in a Console App context

Tags: docusignapi

I am struggling to get access tokens from .net console app context. I am getting them and they work, but they expire too fast.

I checked the other two threads in stackoverflow, in both answers it was stated, that once you get the consent per IK and per user, you don't have to do it anymore. However once I get the bearer token from the return_url and use it to request the access tokens a few minutes after the bearer was obtained, I get response with "**error_description:expired_client_token**".

So me manually obtaining bearer from the browser in order to set it as a parameter (again manually) in my console app and having the bearer expiration duration just a few minutes doesn't match "Consent is needed only once, ever, per a specific integration and a user".
I see that docusign uses cookies' values/expiration and can probably reverse engineer a GET call to account-d.docusign to get the bearer from the console app context, but that's not what I'd expect from an API provider.

For reference I'm using the following URL to manually get the bearer from the browser:
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=d69848a8-2a93-4d03-ab40-bcabda8a7e8f&redirect_uri=https://www.docusign.com
But as stated above, it does expire in a few mins to get the aforementioned error_description
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response type = `code` is the Authorization Code grant flow.

But for a console app where the implementation of the application is downloaded to the user's machine, the Implicit grant flow must be used.

This is because the Authorization Code grant flow includes a second API call, from the app to the OAuth Service Provider. This second call is used to exchange the authorization code for an access token. This second call requires a secret value, but there is no guaranteed method for keeping a secret in an app that's downloaded to the user's machine.

The Implicit grant flow immediately returns the access token to your app for use in calling the API.

### Using the Implicit grant with a console app

Here are the steps. I also discuss this use case in my [Electron React apps post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/electron-react-apps-implicit-grant).

The key is to use `Private-Use URI Scheme Redirection` to handle the authentication and receive the resulting access token. See [RFC 8252 §7.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-7.1)

1. Your app registers a http private scheme such as com.example.name_of_my_app with the operating system (windows). This way, any URL like `com.example.name_of_my_app://app` will be directed to your application to be processed.
2. Configure your DocuSign client id (integration key) to enable implicit grant and to use `com.example.name_of_my_app://app` as a return URL. No secret is needed.

When a user wants to authenticate with DocuSign via your app:

1. Your app initiates the implicit grant flow with the DocuSign OAuth Service Provider by "opening" the URL

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=token&
    scope=signature&client_id=xxxx-xxxx&
    redirect_uri=com.example.name_of_my_app://app
```

2. Windows should open the default browser to the URL. The result will be the authentication page from DocuSign. Your app should NOT open a web view or similar. The operating system's browser should be automatically activated.
3. After the authentication is done, consent will be requested if needed.
4. Next, DocuSign will respond to the browser with a redirect to the redirect_uri. This will trigger your application and give your application the access token needed for API calls to DocuSign.
5. For some operating systems, your app can close the browser window that was created as a result of its URL open.

See the [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/electron-react-apps-implicit-grant) for more info.

### Added

As Ben says, your specific problem is that the authorization code that you receive back in the first step of the Authorization Code grant flow only lasts a minute or so. During that time, you exchange it for an access token (which lasts for 8 hours). But as I say above, you should not be using the authorization code grant flow, you should be using the implicit grant flow.

Comment: Thank you Larry, I apparently missed this crucial part of the equation:
"...you should not be using the authorization code grant flow, you should be using the implicit grant flow."

Answer (score 1):

The token in the response only lasts about 2 minutes. Its true that consent is only needed once, but your problem is not consent.